# Difference Between ADD and SUM in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sum, addition

SUM function results explanation when given two 2-d arrays

When I run the Code in Spyder IDE the Sum function and numpy.add function is showing different results. Can anyone help me to understand how the "SUM" function output is coming when we had given two , 2-d arrays for two parameters in the sum function instead of array and a number. Thank you

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]], dtype=np.float64)
y = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]], dtype=np.float64)

print(x)
print(y)
print (x+y)    
print(sum(x,y))
print(np.add(x,y))




        Output
[[1. 2.]
 [3. 4.]]
[[5. 6.]
 [7. 8.]]
[[ 6.  8.]
 [10. 12.]]
[[ 9. 12.]
 [11. 14.]]
[[ 6.  8.]
 [10. 12.]]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Numpy, the `+` operator is defined to be element-wise addition and in fact [equivalent](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/ufuncs.html#available-ufuncs) to [`np.add(...)`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.add.html#numpy.add).

The [`sum(iterable, [start])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) built-in function

> Sums *start* and the items of an *iterable* from left to right and returns the total. start defaults to 0.

So if only given one matrix, it will perform a column-wise summation. If given a second argument, it will (element-wise) add to the sum. So some smaller examples might be

```
sum(x)
> array([4., 6.])
# i.e. [(1+3), (2+4)]

sum(x, 1)
> array([5., 7.])
# i.e. [(1+1+3), (1+2+4)]

sum(y)
> array([12., 14.])
# i.e. [(5+7), (6+8)]

sum(x, sum(y))
> array([16., 20.])
# i.e. [((5+7)+1+3), ((6+8)+2+4)]

sum(x, y)
> array([[ 9., 12.],
         [11., 14.]])
# i.e. [[(5+1+3), (6+2+4)],
#       [(7+1+3), (8+2+4)]]
```

The last `sum()` is performing the column-wise sum of `x`, and then adding the result to each element of `y` with a shared column. Written with Numpy, it's equivalent to

```
sum(x, y) == x.sum(axis=0) + y
```

Comment: I never used the sum() function. It has interesting behavior. I don't see a use (for my purposes). How do others use it?

Comment: It's a built-in with the intent of summing built-in types like `list`. An example could be if you have a list of numbers `L` you could get its sum `sum(L)` rather than instantiating a variable and looping over each element.

Comment: That said, if you're working with Numpy, it's best to use Numpy's functions. Almost all of the low-level ones (especially `.add()`) are heavily optimized and have sister methods in libraries like [CuPy](https://cupy.chainer.org/).

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I do most of my 'heavy math' with Numpy. In hindsight, I've probably used `sum()` on a list of integers, but not with ndarrays (and certainly not with pairs of ndarrays). Good to know.

Comment: Ironically, I had to sum values from a dictionary today...This was a timely reminder (along with another SO post that showed how to do that).